# Clean way to create scatter plot from x and y vectors

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization

I am building a d3.js scatter plot visualization using Ruby for the backend.
The x and y values outputted by my ruby code is structured in two vectors, x and y.

Is there an easy way to plot the dots as a scatter plot straight from the vectors? Since I'm new to d3, I have been using Scott Murray's [tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) as reference to create my scatter plots, but he uses an array of pairs of values instead of x and y vectors.

I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
svg.selectAll("one_circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "datapoint")
    .attr("cx", function(d){
        return xscale(x[d]);
        })
    .attr("cy", function(d){
        return yscale(y[d]);
        })
    .attr("r", 2);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what `dataset` is in your code snippet, but assuming x and y are the vectors you mentioned, this should work:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.datapoint")
    .data(d3.zip(x,y))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "datapoint")
    .attr("cx", function(d){
        return xscale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d){
        return yscale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", 2);
```

What d3.zip does is take N arrays, the shortest of which is M elements long, and create an M element array of N element arrays using the corresponding elements from each input array.  For example, if the input arrays, x and y, looked like this when calling d3.zip:

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
y = [5,6,7,8];
```

then the output from d3.zip(x,y) would be:

```
[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]
```

exactly what you need to position four circles.  I also changed your element selector to match the elements you're creating...

---

If you really just want to access x and y directly without zipping them into another array, you could do this, although it's a bit of a hack:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.datapoint")
    .data(x.length < y.length ? x : y)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "datapoint")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){
        return xscale(x[i]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i){
        return yscale(y[i]);
    })
    .attr("r", 2);
```

Here were using the shorter of x and y to control the number of circles to draw, and then directly indexing into x and y with the second i parameter to the attr callbacks that indicate which circle is being drawn.

Comment: Thanks @Ray that is exactly what I needed! I didn't know about the zip function, thanks! Indeed, my dataset wasn't clear, x and y should have been dataset["x"] and dataset["y"], since they came from a JSON object, but i figured it out!